# Average of 1'st, 5'th, 10'th,15'th and 25'th cell in excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I need to calculate the average of certain cells of a row in an *excel* sheet. Screenshot:

[image]

I want the average of row 83 (only 1'st(D83), 5'th(H83), 10'th(M83),15'th(R83), 20'th(W83) and 25'th(AB83) cell).

I tried the formula below and it is working fine for 5'th(H83), 10'th(M83), 15'th(R83), 20'th(W83) and 25'th(AB83) cell (not including 1'st row, (but I want 1'st row also)):

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN($D$83:$AB$83)-CELL("Row",$D$83:$AB$83)+0,5)=0,($D$83:$AB$83)))
```

But I also want the same thing for row 86. But it also contains "#DIV/0!".

So I want a condition: there must be at least 3 values (1'st(D86), 5'th(H86), 10'th(M86)), which does not contain `#DIV/0!`, means as row 86 only has values till `K86`. So it should now calculate the average from `D86:K87` (all 8 cells).

But if M86 has value then it should calculate the average using 1'st(D86), 5'th(H86), 10'th(M86), 15'th(R86), 20'th(W86) and 25'th(AB86) cell.

For example :-

Final result for row 83 : (D83+H83+M83+R83+W83+AB83)/6

=>But for row 86: As L86 and above not have ant value (contains "#DIV/0!"). so It should calculate average from AVERAGE(D86:K87) or till column that not has "#DIV/0!".

=>There can be situation if M86 has some value (means we have at least 3 points), so it should do (D86+H86+M86)/3.

=> And if column R has value than it should also include R86 and so on for column W and column AB.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same solution and found below formulas.

=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN($D$83:$AB$83)-CELL("Row",$D$83:$AB$83)+0,5)=0,($D$83:$AB$83)))

And for row 86 please try 
=IF(M86<>0,AVERAGE(IF(MOD(COLUMN($D$86:$AB$86)-CELL("Row",$D$86:$AB$86)+3,5)=0,($D$86:$AB$86))),AVERAGEIF(D86:AB86,"<>0"))

Hope it works for you.